ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa' when using Mozilla TTS
I'm currently working on voice recognition and trying to use the Mozilla TTS library:
!git clone https://github.com/mozilla/TTS.git
%cd TTS
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install soundfile
!pip install torch

Here is my import code, I am using a conda environment with Python 3.9.7:
import os
import shutil
import json
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
from TTS.utils.audio import AudioProcessor
from TTS.utils.text import symbols, phonemes
from TTS.utils.generic_utils import setup_model
from TTS.config.shared_configs import BaseDatasetConfig, BaseAudioConfig

However, when I run the code, I encounter the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20456/222246268.py in <module>
     14 import numpy as np
     15 import soundfile as sf
---> 16 from TTS.utils.audio import AudioProcessor
     17 from TTS.utils.text import symbols, phonemes
     18 from TTS.utils.generic_utils import setup_model

d:\TTS\TTS\utils\audio.py in <module>
----> 1 import librosa
      2 import soundfile as sf
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import scipy.io.wavfile
      5 import scipy.signal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'

I did not use librosa directly anywhere in my code. Is this a dependency issue? How can I resolve this error?

When you did !pip install -r requirements.txt, do you understand what this means? Did you try to look at the requirements.txt file, to see what requirements are being installed? Did you try to check what packages were installed, when you used this command? (Do you know how to?) Do you see librosa installed in the environment?

Does Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment help?
